# NSManagedObjectContext does not work in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
@IBAction func btnSave(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext    
}
```

This does not work since it says it is not unwrapped.

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `managedObjectContext` in application delegate is optional you should unwrap it with an exclamation mark change your code to this:

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
```

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap it, and then continue in a safe way with an if statement like so.

```
@IBAction func btnSave(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext! as NSManagedObjectContext {
        // safe to use the context here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change in AppDelegate madelURL ?

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("**YOURPROJECTNAME**", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```